# Which is better to get return value, by const&, by &&, or just by value?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lifetime, temporary-objects

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> f()
{
    return std::vector<int>(1024);
}

void use_1(std::vector<int> const&)
{}

void use_2(std::vector<int> const&)
{}

int main()
{
    {
        auto const& v = f(); // style 1
        use_1(v);
        use_2(v);
    }

    {
        auto&& v = f(); // style 2
        use_1(v);
        use_2(v);
    }

    {
        auto v = f(); // style 3
        use_1(v);
        use_2(v);
    }
}
```

**Which is better? *style 1*, *style 2*, or *style 3*?**

In my opinion, if the return type doesn't implement move-semantics, then *style 1* and *style 2* are more efficient than *style 3*.

Comment: (3) is the most straightforward. (1) and (2) require you to know about lifetime extension, which isn't exactly widely known.

Comment: why not `std::vector<int> v = f();` ? what do you expect to gain by using a reference?

Comment: `auto v = f();` is equivalent to `std::vector<int> v = f()`. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @xmllmx I know, but my question holds: Why not the most simple `std::vector<int> v = f();` and if you like to add auto `auto v = f();`, but I dont understand why the others

Comment: _"In my opinion...style 1 and style 2 are more efficient"_ Not correct.  C++17 guarantees copy elision in your return, which was already common in compilers for earlier standards.  All forms are equally efficient.

Comment: If the return type doesn't implement move-semantics, simply don't invite it to your party. Having said that, it is not less efficient even in that case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By-value won't be wrong and it's no-less efficient. The life-time is clear, it won't ever dangle. Reference versions are error-prone. Take this example:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct Bar {};

template <class T>
auto&& foo(T&& t) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

int main() { 
  auto&& bar = foo(Bar{});
  // bar dangles
}
```

You may think "this will never happen" but as the code base gets more complicated it does happen. Keep it simple.